# KVM : What is the Maximum Number of Physical CPU and Physical Core KVM Can Support on a Single HOST

Tags: kvm-virtualization, hypervisor, ubuntu-22.04, rocky-linux

I am new here so this is my first day with a very confusing Quistion so please help me to understand it Properly. Expert Advise Required

My Quastion is :

I have a dell PowerEDGE Server With Intel Scalable CPU 24 Cores and 64GB RAM on it, if i install KVM Hypervisor (Ubuntu Or Rocky Linux) in that hardware so can KVM Supports All the Cores or any limitation is there and if Support all the core so how many VM i can create on that?

i dont know i have written it properly or not but still i am eagerly waiting for the replies.

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KVM: maximum number of cores and amount of memory for VMs](https://serverfault.com/questions/343756/kvm-maximum-number-of-cores-and-amount-of-memory-for-vms)